# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException after deploy on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, heroku

I have a problem with an app after I deployed it on Heroku service (but on local machine it's still working fine)

Error message is:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"timestamp":1497005957771,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException","message":"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet","path":"/reports/by1/2017-06-09"},"status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/reports/by1/2017-06-09","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest","X-XSRF-TOKEN":"fd7aca17-d409-4922-85e0-d6b72bc8d6f0"}},"statusText":""}

Hibernate query on local is :

> Hibernate: select report0_.id as id1_6_, report0_.date as date2_6_, report0_.input as input3_6_, report0_.line_id as line_id4_6_, report0_.output as output5_6_, report0_.register as register6_6_, report0_.shift as shift7_6_ from report report0_ where report0_.line_id=? and report0_.date=?

Hibernate query online is : well, that's another question, cuz I cannot read it the error log is to big. Probably the answer to that question would be the answer for both :)

Report.class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
private Date date;
@Column(name = "shift", nullable = false)
private Integer shift;
@Column(name = "register", nullable = false)
private Integer register;
@Column(name = "input", nullable = false)
private Integer input;
@Column(name = "output", nullable = false)
private Integer output;
@Column(name = "line_id", nullable = false)
private Integer lineId;  . . . some code is ommited . . .
```

App is availiable on: https://counter-proj2.herokuapp.com/

login:alex, pass: 123456

Git: https://github.com/ajaks84/CP_ver2

Any thoughts what could be a reason?

By the way, I would be very thankfull for any comment about the app.

Comment: 500 is an internal srever error. You should look into the Server logfiles for more informations

Comment: Well, the problem is: I have no idea how to look in server log files. I'm using a Heroku CLI, and when I got an error I just unable to scroll up enought to see what is happened. Sounds silly, I know. Hope I find the way during the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved. I installed ConEmu and finally saw the error which has happened on Heroku. That wasn't about sql.Date it was just wrong sql script.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things I don't like/smell bad.

a) ReportRepo 
    List findByLineIdAndDate(Integer **line_id**, Date date);

on the repo you need to use the variable name, not the column name. Might not be the cause of your problem, but it looks very ugly.

b) import java.sql.Date;

Only god knows how heroku DB handles java.sql.Date, which is one of the worst implementations in the history of java. I'd switch to a simple java.util.Date or even an Instant, and make sure the heroku DB is using the right datatype

Comment: Thank you for the answer, probably you are right about sql.Date. There is only one table in DB which is uses dates. I'll check it after weekend.

Comment: As for line_id, yeah looks not good, but there is a very small chance that this might be the cause, 0,00001%. Anyway that would be corrected acording Java convention.